# Error using count in insert query SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, count

I've got a query that works fine when I run it on its own, but when I try to put it in a temp table I get the Message:

> 'An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO
>   statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look
>   for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [ ] are not allowed.
>   Change the alias to a valid name.'

The original query is:

```
select t.vc, vn, td, bc, COUNT(*) 
FROM Tractors t
join Vehicles tv on t.vc=tv.vc
where Td >= '2013-05-01' and Td <= '2013-05-31' and bc in ('X', 'I')
group by  t.vc, vn, td, bc
```

The temp table query is:

```
   IF Object_id(N'tempdb..#TC', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TC;
   select t.vc, vn, td, bc, COUNT(*) 
   INTO #TC 
   FROM Tractors t
   join Vehicles tv on t.vc=tv.vc
   where Td >= '2013-05-01' and Td <= '2013-05-31' and bc in ('X', 'I')
   group by  t.vc, vn, td, bc
```

Its probably an obvious fix, but any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you all columns have to have a name, but your count doesn't, so you have to give it one, e.g.:

```
select t.vc, vn, td, bc, COUNT(*) AS Tractors
```

Comment: Yes, to clarify, the fields all need a valid name that the temp table can use as the field name

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error description, each column in the TEMP table needs to have a name.  So, try this:

```
IF Object_id(N'tempdb..#TC', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TC;
select t.vc, vn, td, bc, COUNT(*) as CNT
INTO #TC 
FROM Tractors t
join Vehicles tv on t.vc=tv.vc
where Td >= '2013-05-01' and Td <= '2013-05-31' and bc in ('X', 'I')
group by  t.vc, vn, td, bc
```